# ¿Alguna idea con una lógica de un carrusel con scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Tengo unas dudas sobre cómo arreglar un detalle de un carrusel. El detalle es que al presionar el "left carousel-controls" la imagen se desplaza al último item, pero también debe de desplazarse al final del scroll que está a la derecha o cuando voy pasando al quinto item con la flecha derecha del carrusel y luego regreso al anterior, se baja el scroll un poco y no debería pasar. Lo que sí hace bien es baja el scroll cuando le doy a la derecha y sube cuando regreso. Es un detalle de lógica, ¿alguna idea? (Revisar el js para ver la lógica

```js
$('#home-slider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  
  var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
  var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
  
  $('.list-group-item').eq(slideFrom).removeClass('active');
  $('.list-group-item').eq(slideTo).addClass('active');


  if (slideTo>=4) {
   $('.list-group').animate({scrollTop: '+=84'});
  } 
  
  /*if (Math.max(slideTo)) {
   $('.list-group').animate({scrollTop: 0});
  }*/
  else {
   $('.list-group').animate({scrollTop: '-=84'});
  }

});
```

```css
body {
margin: 40px;
}

.container {
width: 900px; 
}

.slider {
z-index: 2;
height: auto;

    a {
        color: white;
    }

    /*.item {
        img {
            height: 377px;
        }
     } */
}

.slider-list {
    z-index: -99;
     height: 340px;
    margin-left: -32px;

    .list-group-item {
         height: 95px;
         p {
           margin-bottom: 5px;
           font-size: small;
           color: orange;
         }
     }

    .active {
      background-color: ;
      border-color: #ccc;
      color: #333;
      border-left: 4px #f58220 solid;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-color: #ccc;
        color: #333;
        border-left: 4px #f58220 solid;
      }

     }

}
.list-group {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
/*#home_slider .list-group .active {
    background-color: #89c213;  
}*/

.list-group a {
    height: 84px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cod/css/style2.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      
      <div class="slider">
      
        <div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>-->

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/sitios/biblioteca_virtual/contenido/cursos_bv.html">
                <img src="img/carusel/agosto/bib_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/curso.phpx">
                 <img src="img/carusel/agosto/talleres.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/merida_talento.phpx">
                <img src="img/carusel/junio/talento_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/sitios/biblioteca_virtual/contenido/cursos_bv.html">
                <img src="img/carusel/agosto/bib_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/curso.phpx">
                 <img src="img/carusel/agosto/talleres.png">
             </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/merida_talento.phpx">
                <img src="img/carusel/junio/talento_enterate.png">
             </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://isla.merida.gob.mx/serviciosinternet/portal/pcivil/boletin.phpx">
               <img src="img/carusel/agosto/naranja.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>

          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a id="rowRight" class="right carousel-control" href="#home-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
      
      <div class="list-group slider-list" >
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="0">
          <p>HOMENAGEM</p>
          Sindilegis debate demandas prioritárias com o Depol. 
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="1">
          <p>PLANO DE CARREIRA</p>
          Crédito consignado de 120 meses para servidores do Senado
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="2">
          <p>Modo</p>
          Ted
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="3">
          <p>BENEFICIOS</p>
          Pressão para votar a PEC 555
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="4">
          <p>Horizonte</p>
          Excepcional
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="5">
          <p>Prueba</p>
          Otra cosa
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="6">
          <p>Overflow</p>
          Métele con todo
        </a>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cod/js/carrusel_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

)
Es como un carrusel que está en http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/index.phpx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta utilizar ningún if, tienes los parámetros necesarios para calcular scrollTop:

- slideTo (índice)
- 84 (px de alto)

Tu código quedaría así de sencillo:

```js
$('#home-slider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  
  var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
  var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
  
  $('.list-group-item').eq(slideFrom).removeClass('active');
  $('.list-group-item').eq(slideTo).addClass('active');


  $('.list-group').animate({scrollTop: slideTo * 84 });
});
```

```css
body {
margin: 40px;
}

.container {
width: 900px; 
}

.slider {
z-index: 2;
height: auto;

    a {
        color: white;
    }

    /*.item {
        img {
            height: 377px;
        }
     } */
}

.slider-list {
    z-index: -99;
     height: 340px;
    margin-left: -32px;

    .list-group-item {
         height: 95px;
         p {
           margin-bottom: 5px;
           font-size: small;
           color: orange;
         }
     }

    .active {
      background-color: ;
      border-color: #ccc;
      color: #333;
      border-left: 4px #f58220 solid;
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-color: #ccc;
        color: #333;
        border-left: 4px #f58220 solid;
      }

     }

}
.list-group {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
/*#home_slider .list-group .active {
    background-color: #89c213;  
}*/

.list-group a {
    height: 84px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cod/css/style2.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      
      <div class="slider">
      
        <div id="home-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>-->

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/sitios/biblioteca_virtual/contenido/cursos_bv.html">
                <img src="img/carusel/agosto/bib_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/curso.phpx">
                 <img src="img/carusel/agosto/talleres.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/merida_talento.phpx">
                <img src="img/carusel/junio/talento_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/sitios/biblioteca_virtual/contenido/cursos_bv.html">
                <img src="img/carusel/agosto/bib_enterate.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/curso.phpx">
                 <img src="img/carusel/agosto/talleres.png">
             </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://www.merida.gob.mx/municipio/portal/actividades/merida_talento.phpx">
                <img src="img/carusel/junio/talento_enterate.png">
             </a>
              
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <a href="http://isla.merida.gob.mx/serviciosinternet/portal/pcivil/boletin.phpx">
               <img src="img/carusel/agosto/naranja.png">
              </a>
              
            </div>

          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a id="rowRight" class="right carousel-control" href="#home-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
      
      <div class="list-group slider-list" >
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="0">
          <p>HOMENAGEM</p>
          Sindilegis debate demandas prioritárias com o Depol. 
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="1">
          <p>PLANO DE CARREIRA</p>
          Crédito consignado de 120 meses para servidores do Senado
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="2">
          <p>Modo</p>
          Ted
        </a>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="3">
          <p>BENEFICIOS</p>
          Pressão para votar a PEC 555
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="4">
          <p>Horizonte</p>
          Excepcional
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="5">
          <p>Prueba</p>
          Otra cosa
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-target="#home-slider" data-slide-to="6">
          <p>Overflow</p>
          Métele con todo
        </a>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cod/js/carrusel_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```