# ¿Cómo evitar interval de carrusel boostrap cuando está en hover fuera de él?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

He intentado que al estar en hover, en algún otra sección del contenedor del carrusel para que se detenga, pero no sale; debería modificar la función carrusel()?
En el JS, puse varias funciones y no salió, (ver también lo que está comentado)

Basado de acá: [Ver post anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95047/alguna-idea-con-una-l%C3%B3gica-de-un-carrusel-con-scroll/95052#95052)

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2300,
      pause: false
    });

$('.list-group-item').on("mouseover", function () {
    /*var control = $(this),
        interval = false;

     setInterval(function(){control}, interval);*/
     ('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: false,
        pause: false
      });
})/*.on('mouseout', function(){clearInterval(setInterval(interval))})*/;



var i;

/*$('.list-group-item').on("mouseover", function () {
    var control = $(this),
        interval = 500;

    i = setInterval(function () {
        control.trigger("click");
    }, interval);
})
.on("mouseout", function () {
    clearInterval(i);
});*/
```

Comment: Hola Josué, ya que tu pregunta se basa en el código de otra respuesta que es ejecutable, sería bueno que tu código también lo fuera. Comparte también el HTML y CSS relacionado para crear un [mcve]. Y lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda para encontrar consejos para mejorar tus preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

encontre un  post aqui mismo pero en ingles que resuelve tu inquietud, el link es https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271054/how-to-change-interval-of-a-bootstrap-carousel-once-it-has-been-initialised , pero te lo voy a adaptar a lo que tu necesitas.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2300,
  pause: false
});
$('.list-group-item').on("mouseover", function () {
    c = $('.carousel')
    opt = c.data()['bs.carousel'].options
    opt.interval= false;
    c.data({options: opt})
})
```

Espero que te ayude en algo.

Slds